How to display variable from backend into a dialogue made using Dialogue Manager by Nathan Hoad
I am using Dialogue Manager by nathan Hoad in my godot project and instead of hardcoding my dialogues i want to fetch the dialouges from my db and display it
~ Villager Chinu: Where am I? Villager: [[Hey|Hello|Howdy]] {player_name}, How are you. Chinu: Hey old man where am I. => END 
so instead of this whole conversation i want to display the whole dialogues that i have written in JSON in db
Is it possible to do so?. I asked chatgpt it suggest me to use JSON files and that didnt work either

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
